# why jquery offsetParent() returns html while the native javascript returns body

Tags: javascript, jquery

when reading jquery source code,I find that sometimes $().offsetParent() returns html while the native js returns body.

```js
while ( offsetParent && ( !jQuery.nodeName( offsetParent, "html" ) && 
 jQuery.css( offsetParent, "position") === "static" ) ) {
  offsetParent = offsetParent.offsetParent;
}
```

here is the case:
when offsetParent is body,here runs the code "offsetParent = offsetParent.offsetParent;"

my test:

```js
 console.log(document.getElementById('div').offsetParent);
 console.log($('#div').offsetParent());
```

the results:

> <body>...</body>
>
> [html, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document,
>   jquery: "2.0.3", constructor: function, init: function…]

but what is the reason ? why jquery do this work?

Comment: Are you just asking why jQuery returns a jQuery object and not the native DOM node, or why the native `offsetParent` will generally return the `body` element, while jQuery will return the `html` element ?

Comment: Lets assume it's the `<body>` vs `<html>` issue, and that shouldn't matter, if the offsetParent method traverses up to that level it just means that there were no other parents that had a position set, i.e. not being static, so it ends up at the top level instead.

Comment: why the native offsetParent will generally return the body element, while jQuery will return the html element

Comment: Because that's what it does, right there in the code, it stops when the `html` element is reached.

Comment: okay,it actually doesn't matter whether jquery returns body or html... thank you O(∩_∩)O~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native `offsetParent` method has different behavior depending on whether the document is in quirks mode or not. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent) says:

> If the element is non-positioned, the nearest table cell or root element (html in standards compliant mode; body in quirks rendering mode) is the offsetParent.

I think jQuery is trying to standardize this, so it always returns `html`. One of the reasons you use a library like jQuery is to hide browser differences.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I've come up with a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's because [`HTMLElement.prototype.offsetParent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsetparent) works like this:

> The `offsetParent` attribute must return the result of running these
>   steps:
>
> 1. If any of the following holds true return null and terminate this algorithm:
>
>    - The element does not have an associated [CSS layout box](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#css-layout-box).
>    - The element is the root element.
>    - The element is [the HTML `body` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#the-html-body-element).
>    - The element’s computed value of the position property is fixed.
> 2. Return the nearest ancestor element of the element for which at least one of the following is true and terminate this algorithm if
>      such an ancestor is found:
>
>    - The computed value of the position property is not static.
>    - It is [the HTML `body` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#the-html-body-element).
>    - The computed value of the position property of the element is static and the ancestor is one of the following [HTML elements](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#html-elements):
>        `td`, `th`, or `table`.
> 3. Return null.

And jQuery's one works like this:

```js
// docElem is the <html> element
var offsetParent = this.offsetParent || docElem;
while (
  offsetParent
  && !jQuery.nodeName( offsetParent, "html" )
  && jQuery.css( offsetParent, "position" ) === "static" )
) {
    offsetParent = offsetParent.offsetParent;
}
return offsetParent || docElem;
```

Therefore,

- The native `offsetParent` will never return the `html` element for any element inside `body`.
- The jQuery's one will keep iterating when the native one returns `body`. So it will get `null`. So it will return the `html` element.